# Is there any event on Click of OK button in Properties Window

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am using this **EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified** method for tracing the changes in the properties window of an element in EA. 
I need to know is there any event on click of “OK/Cancel/Apply” buttons in the properties window of EA.

As shown in the image, i need to know is there any event that will be called particularly on click of "**OK/Cancel/Apply**" buttons of that window

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's either `EA_OnPostNewElement` if the element has been created newly or `EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified` if you have modified an existing element.

Btw. you find both in the help in [this chapter](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/ea_onnotifycontextitemmodified.html) and [this one](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/automation_and_scripting/post-new_events.html).

Comment: Yaa. i tried this event, EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified which is triggered for any change in the properties window, and its triggering multiple times on click of "OK" button in the properties window. So how can i restrict such that this event is triggered only once on click of "OK" button in the properties window.

Comment: Why would you care?

Comment: Actually my requirement is to pop-up my own dialogue if the user is making any changes in the properties window. 
And for this I am using EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified method which is being triggered every time you click.
I need to know how to restrict this triggering on click of “OK” button in the properties window.  
I need to know how to restrict that dialog popping on click of “OK” button in the properties window.

Comment: I don't get it. OK closes the dialog. That won't help preventing it to pop up.

Comment: Yeah, i know that on click of "OK" button it closes the dialog. But can you please tell me is there any event that triggers on click of this "OK" button?

Comment: Read my answer.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. I need to pop up my own dialog on click of OK button.

Comment: I am using this EA_OnNotifyContextItemModified method(this is getting triggered every time i edit my tagged values and also on click of "OK" button) and opening my own dialog on edit of each tagged value in the properties window. And i don't need that dialog to pop up on click of "OK" button. Hope this is understandable.

Comment: So I got your point (why didn't you state it in your question?). Anyhow, my answer stands as it is.

Comment: So you say there is no such event which will be triggered only on click of OK button in the properties window.